# Inkscape keyboard shortcut to toggle tools panel

Tags: inkscape, shortcuts

I'm using Inkscape on a regular basis, and I know well the shortcuts to show a specific tool panel (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>).

I like the docked tool panel that I can fold to have the full canvas size. I can click on the handle to have it fold / unfold. Now on a big screen I'm loosing time to precisely click on that little handle, so I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut, but to no avail sadly.

I thought it might be somewhat a standard shortcut but I can't find it !

Thanks for any help you can provide as I do that tons of times and it is driving me mad ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcut to toggle the dialogs is <kbd>F12</kbd>.  You can see it under *View > Show/Hide Dialogues*. If you are using a laptop, you'll likely need to hold down the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I feel a bit ashamed to not have found this by myself, it seems so obvious. Thanks anyways, hope this helps other users coming here for the same answer.

Comment: @Joel.O No worries, sometimes I can't see something that's staring me in the face!! ;)